# what is the error in the below c program-0001?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int areaOfRectangle(int,int);
int perimeter(int,int);
int main()
{
    int l,b;
    scanf(" %d %d",&l,&b);
    printf("%d %d %d %d",l,b,areaOfRectangle(l,b),perimeter(l,b));
    return 0;
}
int areaOfRectangle(int a,int b)
{
    int area;
    area=a*b;
    return area;
}
int perimeter(int c,int d)
{
    int meter;
    meter=2(c+d);
    return meter;
}
```

why this error:`called object is not a function or function pointer` at line: `meter=2(c+d)`?

Also, can I use the same variable `a,b` to pass in perimeter function?

Comment: `2 * (c + d)`; yes (it's just names)

Comment: The compiler is interpreting `2(...)` as a function call, and then realizing `2` cannot be a function name. As answered below, you want `2 * (...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code `meter=2(c+d);`should be changes as `meter=2*(c+d);`
You can use the same variable a,b to pass in perimeter function, A parameter is just a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

In this statement:

```
int perimeter(int c,int d)
{
    int meter;
    meter=2(c+d);
    return meter;
}
```

You'll obviously get a syntax error since the compiler won't detect `2(c+d)` as you're trying to implicitly multiply 2 with `(c + d)`. Rather, if you explicitly define `2 * (c + d)` then it'll no longer show you any error.

One side tip, you don't need to use any local variables inside a function if you just want to return a simple return statement, rather you may use:

```
return 2 * (c + d);
```

The declaration is redundant thence.